# python create subprocess (newbie)

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm new to python, so here's what I'm looking to get done.
I would like to use python to manage some of my gameservers and start/stop them. For this I would like to run every gameserver in a own process.
What's the best way to create processes using python, so these processes can continue even if the main application is stopped?

To start a server I only need to execute shell code.

How can I get access after stopping my main application and restarting it to these processes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question completely, but maybe something like this?

Run process:

```
import subprocess 

subprocess.Popen(['/path/gameserver']) #keeps running
```

And in another script you can use 'ps -A' to find the pid and kill (or restart) it:

```
import subprocess, signal 

p = subprocess.Popen(['ps', '-A'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
out, err = p.communicate()

for line in out.splitlines(): 
    if 'gameserver' in line: 
        pid = int(line.split(None, 1)[0]) 
        os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `subprocess` module. There is a function called `call`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).
You may need to set the process to not be a daemon process.